# ASP.NET How to Skip Tabbing Over SiteMapPath?

Tags: asp.net, tabindex, sitemappath

How can I skip tabbing over the SiteMapPath? This is what I'm trying to do (code below), but it still focuses on the path links after a few TAB key presses.

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="smp1" runat="server" TabIndex="-1"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab order (unless specified) is driven by the element order in the HTML flow. You'll have to set the `TabIndex` property to a large number as to be enough to skip the number of elements that can receive focus in the browser.